# Disable (exclude) bootstrap for one div on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application that pulls custom old emails and displays them on a page in DOM. I want to exclude a div that contains this HTML email from bootstrap css. Something like this:

```
<div class="email_container">
<!-- bootstrap CSS shouldn't apply here-->
<div class="email">
<!-- neither here-->
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way this can be done? I did some research and saw people talking about LESS and SASS to solve this but is there a way to do this without them as I don't want to include LESS or SASS in my project just for this purpose.

Comment: Might sound dirty, but you could possibly put the HTML email contents into an iframe, this way your styles wouldn't cascade down.

Comment: About excluding look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696810/is-it-possible-to-exclude-all-css-styling-for-one-specific-div-container)

Comment: Overwrite the rules with **`!important`**.

Comment: @Stuart I did think of that but I can't because I have to do DOM manipulations on that email HTML

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I can't overwrite as the styles are also coming in from a remote source and I will have to manually override each of them which isn't most optimal

Comment: @Arihant - could you not place the js thats doing the dom manipulations inside the iframe too...?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862867/clear-bootstrap-styling-for-part-of-a-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use this class for reseting all the CSS under `email_container`. In the CSS it says `.reset-this *` so for the elements under `.reset_this` will get reseted, then you can  add what you want.

This was not created by me, it was taken from the link [resetting CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only)

<kbd>**`JSFiddle Demo`**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="email_container reset-this">
<!-- bootstrap CSS shouldn't apply here
<div class="email">
<!-- neither here-->
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.reset-this * {
    animation : none;
    animation-delay : 0;
    animation-direction : normal;
    animation-duration : 0;
    animation-fill-mode : none;
    animation-iteration-count : 1;
    animation-name : none;
    animation-play-state : running;
    animation-timing-function : ease;
    backface-visibility : visible;
    background : 0;
    background-attachment : scroll;
    background-clip : border-box;
    background-color : transparent;
    background-image : none;
    background-origin : padding-box;
    background-position : 0 0;
    background-position-x : 0;
    background-position-y : 0;
    background-repeat : repeat;
    background-size : auto auto;
    border : 0;
    border-style : none;
    border-width : medium;
    border-color : inherit;
    border-bottom : 0;
    border-bottom-color : inherit;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 0;
    border-bottom-style : none;
    border-bottom-width : medium;
    border-collapse : separate;
    border-image : none;
    border-left : 0;
    border-left-color : inherit;
    border-left-style : none;
    border-left-width : medium;
    border-radius : 0;
    border-right : 0;
    border-right-color : inherit;
    border-right-style : none;
    border-right-width : medium;
    border-spacing : 0;
    border-top : 0;
    border-top-color : inherit;
    border-top-left-radius : 0;
    border-top-right-radius : 0;
    border-top-style : none;
    border-top-width : medium;
    bottom : auto;
    box-shadow : none;
    box-sizing : content-box;
    caption-side : top;
    clear : none;
    clip : auto;
    color : inherit;
    columns : auto;
    column-count : auto;
    column-fill : balance;
    column-gap : normal;
    column-rule : medium none currentColor;
    column-rule-color : currentColor;
    column-rule-style : none;
    column-rule-width : none;
    column-span : 1;
    column-width : auto;
    content : normal;
    counter-increment : none;
    counter-reset : none;
    cursor : auto;
    direction : ltr;
    display : inline;
    empty-cells : show;
    float : none;
    font : normal;
    font-family : inherit;
    font-size : medium;
    font-style : normal;
    font-variant : normal;
    font-weight : normal;
    height : auto;
    hyphens : none;
    left : auto;
    letter-spacing : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    list-style : none;
    list-style-image : none;
    list-style-position : outside;
    list-style-type : disc;
    margin : 0;
    margin-bottom : 0;
    margin-left : 0;
    margin-right : 0;
    margin-top : 0;
    max-height : none;
    max-width : none;
    min-height : 0;
    min-width : 0;
    opacity : 1;
    orphans : 0;
    outline : 0;
    outline-color : invert;
    outline-style : none;
    outline-width : medium;
    overflow : visible;
    overflow-x : visible;
    overflow-y : visible;
    padding : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    padding-left : 0;
    padding-right : 0;
    padding-top : 0;
    page-break-after : auto;
    page-break-before : auto;
    page-break-inside : auto;
    perspective : none;
    perspective-origin : 50% 50%;
    position : static;
    /* May need to alter quotes for different locales (e.g fr) */
    quotes : '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019';
    right : auto;
    tab-size : 8;
    table-layout : auto;
    text-align : inherit;
    text-align-last : auto;
    text-decoration : none;
    text-decoration-color : inherit;
    text-decoration-line : none;
    text-decoration-style : solid;
    text-indent : 0;
    text-shadow : none;
    text-transform : none;
    top : auto;
    transform : none;
    transform-style : flat;
    transition : none;
    transition-delay : 0s;
    transition-duration : 0s;
    transition-property : none;
    transition-timing-function : ease;
    unicode-bidi : normal;
    vertical-align : baseline;
    visibility : visible;
    white-space : normal;
    widows : 0;
    width : auto;
    word-spacing : normal;
    z-index : auto;
    /* basic modern patch */
    all: initial;
    all: unset;
}

/* basic modern patch */

#reset-this-root {
    all: initial;
    * {
        all: unset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't not exclude some css style, if bootstrap affect all `div`into the site, eg:

```
div {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  /* some other styles */
}
```

if bootstrap or just another css framework has that, so you can't omit the style written above, so the alternative you have to it, is just add a custom class to your "exclude div", try this

```
<div class="myCustomClassToExclude">
</div>
```

and in your css style

```
.myCustomClassToExclude {
  color: #FFF; /*override color*/
  font-size: 20px; /*override font-size*/
  /* here you need to override all the style already set by bootstrap */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way to achieve this is to recompile the whole bootstrap stylesheets with a CSS preprocessor after wrapping it into a CSS class like :

```
.bootstap-include{  
   /* Content of bootstap.css .. */
}
```

To make it work, the file needs some tweaks :

- Replace the `:root` selector at the top of the file with a `&`
- Replace the `body` selector at the top of the file with a `&`
- Remove the charset declaration `@charset "UTF-8";`

See a working pen here : https://codepen.io/kisaure/pen/WNXOBdz

I didn't test it but I think bootsrap.js functions and some other stuff may be broken.