# How can I make datatables compatible with my theme?

Tags: html, jquery, css, django

I am using a theme that it's has it's own styling defined based on bootstrap 4.5.0

When I try to use datatables( the bootstrap 4 version ) the theme style breaks badlly.

https://datatables.net/

The plugin uses this styling:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

If I don't add it (because I have the bootstrap theme style already reffered) then the table styling breaks. Not so baddly but enough to encourage me not to use the plugin's bootrstap version at all because the default one looks better.

Is there a way to make both work? I would really like to use the boostrap version of the plugin. Looks and feels much cooler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable (exclude) bootstrap for one div on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943585/disable-exclude-bootstrap-for-one-div-on-a-page)

Comment: I am looking for a more clean solution if there is. Perhaps something I am missing here.

Comment: To be clear, you need to rewrite rules manualy in your css or exclude bs from the page that use this table. The subject above is just a trick that you can use to remove css by using specific class that reset all css. You can also check this: https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap

Comment: This is helpful but it looks like it patches things up. Maybe is the only way...